# Remove site name from the post titles?

Tags: wordpress

How to remove or hide my blog name from every post title. For example, when Google indexes my post, I see – MY SITE NAME at the end of all links. Also, I know that is a problem with site because when I paste my link to social media sites I must manually delete site name from the end. How to hide?

I was tried with `add_filter( ‘document_title_parts’, function( $title ) { unset( $title[‘site’] ); return $title; } );`

But with this code, I successfully remove site name from links but I can't pass RSS validator. I get:

```
<channel> <title></title> missing title
```

How get this to work? I am using the GeneratePress WordPress theme.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to add, I don't use SEO plugin!

Comment: Well, I came here to suggest to use Yoast SEO which allow you to easily get this done.

Comment: ...without Yoast Seo, please?